# How can i apply map function to update all element of JSON body

Tags: json, reactjs, api, react-native

```
async editSurvey(answers) {
 let answer_text;
 let id;
 answers.map((answer, index) => {
   answer_text = answer.answer_text;
   id = answer.id;
});

body: JSON.stringify({
    question: {
      answers_attributes: {
        '0': {
          answer_text: answer_text,
          id: id
        } }
    }
  })
}
```

This is api code and i want map function so that on every map it should go to  JSON.stringify and assign the values but in my case it is going to JSON.stringify for last map element. so please suggest me any solution.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async editSurvey(answers) {
 let answer_text;
 let id;
 answers.map((answer, index) => {
   answer_text = answer.answer_text;
   id = answer.id;
   return {
     body: JSON.stringify({
    question: {
      answers_attributes: {
        '0': {
          answer_text: answer_text,
          id: id
        }
     }
    }
   }
});
```

Try doing something like this , check brackets once

Comment: Thank you for your response. its working but need to refresh the page. as initially it is giving error of "ExceptionsManager.js:71 Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined". please suggest the solution.

Comment: How can this work for POST method as it creates complete data for answers.length time, I mean whole data goes inside a loop.